# Create Operator In Postgresql

Tags: postgresql

Anyone knows how to call self defined operator in postgresql? 
I hava the following operator:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION algo.fun_temp(IN exp BOOLEAN)
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN NOT exp;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;

CREATE OPERATOR algo.~
(
PROCEDURE = algo.fun_temp,
RIGHTARG = BOOLEAN
);
```

And when I try to call this operator with `SELECT algo.~ TRUE`, the client complains

```
"ERROR:  syntax error at or near "~"
LINE 1: SELECT algo.~ TRUE"
```

Anyone knows what the problem is? Any help is appreciated.

cheng

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The function should return `INTEGER`, what you wrote returns `BOOLEAN`:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION algo.fun_temp(IN exp BOOLEAN)
RETURNS INTEGER AS $$
BEGIN
    RETURN (NOT exp)::INTEGER;
END;
$$ LANGUAGE plpgsql;
```

Then add the schema `algo` to the `search_path`:

```
SET search_path = public, algo;
```